# Next JS - Problemas al usar next export (Error occurred prerendering page)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

estoy trantando de hacer el build de mi sitio y me sale el siguiente error en cada una de las paginas:

```
$ next export
info  - Loaded env from /Users/xWesko/Desktop/web/client/.env.production
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no custom webpack configuration in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - using build directory: /Users/xWesko/Desktop/web/client/build
info  - Copying "static build" directory
info  - No "exportPathMap" found in "next.config.js". Generating map from "./pages"
info  - Launching 7 workers
info  - Copying "public" directory
[==  ] info  - Exporting (0/14)

Error occurred prerendering page "/noticias". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Error for page /noticias: pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/gssp-export

Error occurred prerendering page "/noticias/[slug]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Error for page /noticias/[slug]: pages with `getServerSideProps` can not be exported. See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/gssp-export
```

y asi con todas las paginas

Mi archivo **next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    basePath: '',
    output: 'export',
    distDir: 'build',
    trailingSlash: true,
}
```

Por ejemplo la pagina es un index.jsx dentro de una carpeta llamada noticias

```
pages/
  noticias/
     index.jsx
     [slug].jsx
```

**noticias.jsx**

```
export default function Noticias ({data}) {
    return ("contenido ...")
}

export async function getServerSideProps({query}) {

  const buscar = query.buscar ? `&buscar=${query.buscar}` : '';
  let params = `ordenar=creado-desc&limite=6&pagina=${query.pagina}${buscar}`;
  const resp = await fetch(`${API_URI}/v1/noticia?${params}`);
  const data = await resp.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    }
  }
}
```

Y lo mismo para el resto de paginas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por qué deseas agregar `output: export`? Esa opción es para generar  [sitios **estáticos**](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export), es decir, que no dependen de datos dinámicos. Al tener `pages` con `getServerSideProps` esas páginas no pueden ser estáticas porque cada vez que alguien las visite `getServerSideProps` va a ejecutarse, y eso es incompatible con un sitio estático. Por eso tu build se está quejando.

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Remover la opción `output: export` de tu `next.config.js`.
2. Usar `getStaticProps` + `getStaticPaths`.

Al usar `getStaticProps` + `getStaticPaths`, los valores que se obtienen de los llamados a API externas se guardan como datos estáticos y se actualizarán cada vez que corras un build solamente, no cada vez que se visite la página.

Puedes leer más sobre `getStaticProps` [aquí](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props).

Comment: Una disculpa, soy algo nuevo con Nextjs, anteriormente con Reactjs hacia un build que me generaba html,css y js y eso lo subia a mi hosting. Quiero hacer eso mismo con next.  Pero mantener las paginas dinamicas como la de noticias ([slug].jsx). Que deberia de usar ?

Comment: No tienes por qué disculparte. Hay varias opciones, remover los `getServerSideProps` y que hagas fetch de tus datos en el cliente: puedes usar una librería como SWR, para ello o un simple fetch dentro de un useEffect. Lo otro es que tu hosting acepte aplicaciones de Next.js como tal, así podrías remover la opción `output: export` y dejar los `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: Okey creo que entendí, voy a probar la segunda opción. Gracias!